# HTML Button, Controls disabled/inactive in grid-container

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to HTML,JavaScript, CSS. This is first time i have ever asked for help online.
I can't understand why all my controls are inactive in this CSS Tab container. The code works fine switching between tabs, but none of the button or controls are clickable. Sure I'm overlooking something easy..
I really would appreciate anyone's help!
Full index page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title id = "DeviceNameP">Test System</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body {font-family: Arial; background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0066cc 0%, #ffffff 100%) fixed;}
            .caret {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 6px solid transparent;
            }
            .caret.down{
            border-top-color: black; position: relative; top: 5px;
            }
            .caret.right{
            border-left-color: black;
            }
            .caret.up{
            border-bottom-color: black;
            }
            .caret.left{
            border-right-color: black;
            }

            hr { display: block; margin-before: 0.5em; margin-after: 0.5em; margin-start: auto; margin-end: auto; overflow: hidden; border-style: inset; border-width: 1px;}

            .item1 { grid-area: header; }
            .item2 { grid-area: menu; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
            .item3 { grid-area: main;  height:1fr; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 2px solid #ccc; overflow: auto;}
            .item4 { grid-area: right;  height:1fr; overflow: auto; }
            .item5 { grid-area: footer; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;}

            .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns:    1.5fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows:    75px 35px auto 25px;
            grid-template-areas:
            'header header '
            'menu menu  '
            'main right'
            'footer footer';
            grid-gap: 0px;
            background-color: inherit; /* 2196F3 the tab */
            padding: 4px 4px;
            /* width: 100vw; */
            /* height: 100vh; */
            }

            .grid-container  div {
            background-color: inherit;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 0px 4px;
            font-size: 12px;
            }
            .grid-container iframe {display:block; width: 100%; height: 500px;  border: none; margin: 0; padding:4px 0px;}

            @media only screen and (orientation: portrait ) {
            .grid-container {
            grid-template-rows:    75px 35px auto auto 25px;
            grid-template-areas:
            'header header '
            'menu menu  '
            'main main'
            'right right'
            'footer footer';
            }
            .item4 { border: 3px solid yellow;  padding-before: 5px;}
            }
            /* Style the tab */
            .tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: none;
            }

            /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
            .tab button {
            background-color: #inherate;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 4px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
            }

            /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
            .tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            }

            /* Create an active/current tablink class */
            .tab button.active {
            background-color: #66ff66;
            }

            /* Style the tab content */
            .tabcontent {
            display: none;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1" >
            <div>
                <h2 id="DeviceName" >Device Name</h2>
                <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='logo.png')}}"  style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0; width: 50px;height: 50px; border: none;"></img>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item2">
            <div class="tab">
                <button id = "Start_Tab" class="tablinks" onclick="openStatusTab(event, 'Status')">Device Status</button>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSettingsTab(event, 'Settings')">Device Settings</button>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Network') ">User Access </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item3">
            <div id="Status" class="tabcontent" >
                <h3>Settings</h3>
                <div>
                   <div  style="margin-top:10 px">
                   <label> </label> <br>
                    <button id = "Save_Button" onclick="SaveValues()" >Save Changes</button>
                    <button id = "Cancel_Button" onclick="FillValues()">Cancel</button>
                    <button id = "Restart_Button" onclick="DoCommand('Restart','')">Restart Device</button>
                    <button id = "RestartDef_Button" onclick="DoCommand('Restart','ResetDefaults')">Reset To Defaults</button>
            
                    <label> </label> <br>
                   </div> 
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item3">
            <div id="Settings" class="tabcontent">
                <style> 
                    table.input td.desc {text-align: right; }
                    table.input td.ip {text-align: right; width: 10px; }
                </style>

                <div>
                   <div  style="margin-top:10 px">
                   <label> </label> <br>
                    <button id = "Save_Button" onclick="SaveValues()" >Save Changes</button>
                    <button id = "Cancel_Button" onclick="FillValues()">Cancel</button>
                    <button id = "Restart_Button" onclick="DoCommand('Restart','')">Restart Device</button>
                    <button id = "RestartDef_Button" onclick="DoCommand('Restart','ResetDefaults')">Reset To Defaults</button>
            
                    <label> </label> <br>
                   </div>
                   <h3 style="margin-bottom: 2px;">Device Settings</h3>
                    <table class="input" style= "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="desc"><label>Location Name:</label> </td> <td><input type="text" class="VText" id="LocationName_V"  ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="desc"><label>Device Name:</label></td> <td><input type="text" class="VText" id="DeviceName_V";></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <hr>

                    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 2px;">Device Type</h3>
                    <table class="input" style= "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="desc"><label>Device Type:</label></td>
                            <td>
                              <select id="DeviceType_V" class="VText">
                                <option value="0">Gate Access</option>
                                <option value="1">Countdown Timer</option>
                                <option value="2">Vending Machine</option>
                                <option value="3">Access Period</option>
                                <option value="4">Access Period (Scan In/Scan Out)</option>
                              </select> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="desc"><label>Timer (sec):</label> </td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="VText"  id="TimerSec_V"; value="15" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="desc"><label >Cost$:</label> </td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="VText"  id="TimerSec_V"; value="0.00" ></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item3">
            <div id="Network" class="tabcontent" >
                <style> 
                    table.input td.desc {text-align: right; }
                    table.input td.ip {text-align: right; width: 10px; }
                </style>
                               
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item4">
            <div id="StatusHelp" class="tabcontent"  >
                <h3>Settings description</h3>
                 {% include 'StatusHelp.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item4">
            <div id="SettingsHelp" class="tabcontent">
                <h3>Settings description</h3>
                {% include 'SettingsHelp.html' %} 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item4">
            <div id="NetworkHelp" class="tabcontent" >
                <h3>Network</h3>
                {% include 'NetworkHelp.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item5">Footer</div>
        </div>
<script>
    function openStatusTab(evt, TabName) {
        Hidesections();
        document.getElementById(TabName + "Help").style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById(TabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        //document.getElementById(TabName).innerHTML = "";
        //GetinnerHTML(TabName);
        //GetinnerHTMLHelp(TabName);
    }
    function openSettingsTab(evt, TabName) {
        Hidesections();
        document.getElementById(TabName + "Help").style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById(TabName).style.display = "block";
        console.log(evt.currentTarget.className);
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        //LoadSettings();
        //FillValues();
        //GetinnerHTML(TabName);
        //GetinnerHTMLHelp(TabName);
    }
    function openTab(evt, TabName) {
        Hidesections();
        document.getElementById(TabName + "Help").style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById(TabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        //GetinnerHTMLHelp(TabName);
    }

    function GetinnerHTML(TabName) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(TabName).innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/" +TabName + ".html", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
            
    function GetinnerHTMLHelp(TabName) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(TabName + "Help").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/" +TabName + "Help.html", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function Hidesections()
    {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
    }

    var myObj;
    function LoadSettings() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("DeviceName").innerHTML = "Device Name:" + myObj.DeviceName;
                document.getElementById("DeviceNameP").innerHTML = myObj.DeviceName;
                //document.getElementById("DeviceNameP").innerHTML = myObj.Testing;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/API/GetSettings", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    //window.onload = LoadSettings(); 

    document.getElementById("Start_Tab").click();


    function FillValues()
    {
        var i, ValueFields, tablinks;
        ValueFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VText");
        for (i = 0; i < ValueFields.length; i++) {
         //   console.log(ValueFields[i].id);
         //   console.log(ValueFields[i].id.substr(ValueFields[i].id.length - 2 ));
        //  console.log(myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length - 2 )));
        //  console.log(Object.keys(myObj));
           if(ValueFields[i].id != "" && ValueFields[i].id.endsWith("_V") && myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )))
           {
               ValueFields[i].value = myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )];
               ValueFields[i].name = 'Name' + i;
               ValueFields[i].autocomplete = 'off';
           }
        }
        ValueFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VCheck");
        for (i = 0; i < ValueFields.length; i++) {
        if(ValueFields[i].id != "" && ValueFields[i].id.endsWith("_V") && myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )))
           {
              ValueFields[i].checked = (myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] == 'true');
              ValueFields[i].name = 'NameCheck' + i;
              ValueFields[i].autocomplete = 'off';
           }
        }
    }
    
    function SaveValues()
    {
        var i, ValueFields, tablinks;
        ValueFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VText");
        for (i = 0; i < ValueFields.length; i++) {
           if(ValueFields[i].id != "" && ValueFields[i].id.endsWith("_V") && myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )))
           {
                myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] = ValueFields[i].value;
           }
        }
        ValueFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VCheck");
        for (i = 0; i < ValueFields.length; i++) {
        if(ValueFields[i].id != "" && ValueFields[i].id.endsWith("_V") && myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )))
           {
                if(ValueFields[i].checked)
                    myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] = 'true';
                else 
                    myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] = 'false';
           }
        }
        console.log(myObj);
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('POST', '/API/savesettings', true)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myObj))
    }   

    function DoCommand(Action,Command)
    {
        /* var i, ValueFields, tablinks;
        ValueFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VText");
        for (i = 0; i < ValueFields.length; i++) {
           if(ValueFields[i].id != "" && ValueFields[i].id.endsWith("_V") && myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )))
           {
                myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] = ValueFields[i].value;
           }
        }
        ValueFields = document.getElementsByClassName("VCheck");
        for (i = 0; i < ValueFields.length; i++) {
        if(ValueFields[i].id != "" && ValueFields[i].id.endsWith("_V") && myObj.hasOwnProperty(ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )))
           {
                if(ValueFields[i].checked)
                    myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] = 'true';
                else 
                    myObj[ValueFields[i].id.substr(0,ValueFields[i].id.length -2 )] = 'false';
           }
        } 
        */
        
        var myCod = { Action , Command};
        console.log(myCod);
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open('POST', '/API/Command', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myCod));
        <!-- if(Action == "Restart" ) location.reload(); -->
    }   

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Pay extra attention to the word **minimal**!

Comment: Technical JS wise you should use `classList.add('class-name')` to add a class to an element instead of `.className += " active"`. Also isntead of looping through every element with a certain class-name you can use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`

Comment: The controls are not inactive, there are div elements that are covering the content you expect to be clickable. Specifically the item1,item2, item3... etc classes should be examined, because they are stacking over one another.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a hint why you cannot click on your buttons by inspect them.
Right click on your buttons and Inspect. You'll see that the element inspected will be your last "item3".
The same behavior happens when you're trying to click on your button. You think you click on your button, however you really click on the last div "item3".

Comment: Thanks, That helped a lot. Didn't know you could right-click on control and see what it thinks it sees. From that I removed the extra "Item3" and "item4" div and just made them one.. Works great now.. Thanks again to all...